# Haskell comparing two lists' lengths but one of them is infinite?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a function that checks if the first list is longer than the second list and one of them can be infinite. However I can't find a working solution.

```
isLonger :: [a] -> [b] -> Bool
isLonger a b 
        | listLength a > listLength b = True
        |otherwise = False

listLength :: [a] -> Integer
listLength = foldr (flip $ const . (+1)) 0
```

Comment: You can't get the length of an infinite list. You'll need to traverse both lists in parallel, until you find the shorter one.

Comment: And BTW `foldr (flip $ const . (+1)) 0` is a horribly arcane implementation of `length`, where did you find that? As Bergi commented, you should actually not be computing lengths at all.

Comment: Somewhat related: if you want to determine which of two persons is the tallest, do you need to measure them and compare the lengths, or can you have them stand next to each other and look?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

@dfeuer's solution  wins on cleverness, but in terms of a more typical solution...

A reasonable approach mentioned in the comments is to process both lists in parallel and figure out which one "runs out" first -- that's the shorter list.  A simple  solution is to recurse while both lists are non-empty:

```
isLonger :: [a] -> [b] -> Bool
isLonger (x:xs) (y:ys) = isLonger xs ys
```

and return an answer as soon as one of the lists becomes empty:

```
isLonger []     _  = False   -- list a <= list b
isLonger _      [] = True    -- list a > list b
```

If both lists run out at the same time (equal length), the first pattern will match, so that will determine the answer in case of a tie.

Answer (score 21):

Plain old natural numbers will not do the trick, because you can't calculate the natural number length of an infinite list in finite time. However, *lazy* natural numbers can do it.

```
import Data.Function (on)

data Nat = Z | S Nat
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

len :: [a] -> Nat
len = foldr (const S) Z

isLonger :: [a] -> [b] -> Bool
isLonger = (>) `on` len
```

You can do it even more compactly using lists to represent lazy natural numbers.

```
isLonger :: [a] -> [b] -> Bool
isLonger = (>) `on` (() <$)
```

Of course, if both lists are infinite, you are doomed to an infinite loop no matter what you do.

---

If you are worried about incompletely defined lists as well as infinite ones, you can be a little lazier using a custom `Ord` instance for `Nat`:

```
instance Ord Nat where
  compare Z Z = EQ
  compare Z (S _) = LT
  compare (S _) Z = GT
  compare (S x) (S y) = compare x y

  Z <= _ = True  -- lazy in the second argument
  S _ <= Z = False
  S x <= S y = x <= y

  x >= y = y <= x
  x > y = not (x <= y)
  x < y = y > x
```

Now if the first list is empty, `isLonger` will return `False` even if the second list is undefined.

Comment: I’m intrigued by your last solution route but am not sufficiently familiar with Haskell to tease it apart. Can you elaborate on what `(() <$)` means?

Comment: @templatetypedef it means `map (const ())`.

Comment: @templatetypedef more precisely, it means `fmap (const ())` but here `fmap = map`.